# Text becomes automatically capital in input field form. I am working on PHP and Codeigniter3

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, codeigniter

When I type any text in the input field it automatically becomes capital, whereas I haven't used anything like strtouppercase and also the caps lock is off. I am working in admin panel and facing this issue whereas in student form there are also forms but there I am not facing as such problem.

I want the text to be types as I want. Be it uppercase lowercase or first word capital but here in this case each character becomes capital.

This is my controller code:

```
//This method is for loading the view.

public function updatedirectorMessage()
    {
        $data['side_bar_values'] = $this->side_bar_values;
        $this->view("admin/update_director_message", $data);
    }
```

```
//This method is for inserting data.

public function update_directorMessage_handler()
    {
        $description = $this->input->post('director_message');
        $this->Configuration_model->updateConfiguration('DIRECTOR_MESSAGE', $description);
    }
```

This is my model code

```
function updateConfiguration($title,$description){
        $this->db->where('TITLE',$title);
        $data['DESCRIPTION'] =$description;
        $this->db->update('configuration',$data);
    }
```

This is my view code

```
<div id="min-height" class="container-fluid" style="padding:30px">
    <div class='card'>
        <div class="card-body">
    
            <form action="<?=base_url()?>AdminPanel/update_directorMessage_handler" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Director Message</label>
                   
                    <textarea name="director_message" id="" cols="30" rows="10" ><?=$director_message?></textarea>
                 
                    
                    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" >
                    
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *When I type any text in the input field it automatically becomes capital*? If that happens when you type then check CSS and/or javascript for that input field (btw. it looks like to be a textarea, what you are referring to?)

Comment: yes here in this form I have used text area but in other form there is text field which is causing the same problem as well

Comment: add `style="text-transform: none;"`to your <textarea> tag

Comment: I have just tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: did you apply the style inline? like `<textarea style="text-transform: none;">`

Comment: yes I applied in that way

Comment: Then I can only imagine that a javascript/jquery script is overwriting the css style somewhere, when document loads. Right-click in your browser over the textarea and check the style, which it has applied in the browser's inspector

Comment: Is this happening with this specific project? 
What happens when you comment out some JavaScript or CSS files?

Comment: what exactly to check in console? because I don't find any such style or property that might be causing this. Maybe as you said it's because of javascript/jquery

Comment: in the browser's **inspector** (press F12), you can see how an element is styled at output. You can take your conclusions (find the problem) from there. The browser' tabs you'll find: Inspector != Console != Network, etc...